# Como mostrar un mensaje de Cargando Datos al momento de realizar una consulta?

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Buen dia ,
Compañeros me podrían ayudar en como mostrar un mensaje cuando presiono el botón de consultar,estoy realizando una aplicación web en cual lleno un formulario de rango de fechas y selecciono el tipo de reporte que quiero que me genere , esa parte ya la realiza lo que ahora quiero es mostrar un mensaje de "Cargado datos..." y me bloquee la pantalla para que el usuario visualice que esta trabajando en ello ya que a la hora de realizar las consultas tarda un tiempo en regresarme la información, encontré una forma de que bloquee la pantalla usando   unos scripts pero cuando presiono el boton y me falta algun campo se muestra el div de cargando y ya no lo puedo quitar hasta que yo refresque la pagina la aplicacion esta hecha en asp mvc .

```
<div id="fader" style="display:none">
<div class="centrar">
    <img src="~/Content/images/Load-Engrane.gif" class="center-block" />
    <p class="text-center" style="font-size:medium">Espere un momento, generando informacion...</p>
</div>
```

```
$("#btnEnviar").click(function () {

            $('#fader').css('display', 'block');

    });
```

Comment: Hola, ¿en que momento se sabe que ya se ha cargado los datos? hace falta un detonante para dejar de mostrar el div de cargando.

Comment: hola @the-breaker me retorna la vista con la informacion desplegada , hace como un tipo de refresh y es como se detiene el div

Comment: no veo la función que hace eso en el código, creo que hace falta esa parte ya que es ahí donde radica el problema, debes agregar un código en el caso de que falte algún campo.